newrelic logging, does it affect existing (logback) logging?
Our java spring boot web app runs in AWS.  We want to use newrelic to monitor the api endpoints and their timings.  We dont want anything else, as we cant afford it.  AWS sends our logs to our self install of ELK.
We notice by default its taking the logs into new relic.

does logs being taken into new relic stop logs being taken into new relic, or can they go to both?
currently, we see that all the debug logs are going into NR, even though   log_level: info is set in the newrelic.yml.  How then could we limit just ERROR level lots to be sent to new relic (assuming they are also sent to ELK which we dont know yet).



Logs being captured by the New Relic Java agent do not prevent them from going to other destinations.

The log_level configuration option changes the level at which the agent logs. If you meant application_logging.forwarding.log_level, it does not work (yet) with the Java agent.


You can disable the log forwarding feature by setting application_logging.enabled to false (docs).
